# Completing premed requirements after Bachelors

Tags: graduate-admissions, coursework, medicine

I'm thinking about applying to medical schools in the USA. Many medical schools require a two-year course in chemistry including organic chemistry and a year long course in biology, as well as requirements in mathematics and physics.

I have already satisfied the mathematics and physics requirements and a portion of the chemistry requirements during my undergraduate study. Are there any programs that will let me cherry pick classes to satisfy the application requirements?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. At many (most?) universities in the United States, you can take courses as a non-matriculating student to get your premed requirements.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. Would there be any reason that a school would view courses taken in a standard premed postbac program more positively than courses taken as a non-degree/non-matriculating student?

Comment: @Mark I have never served on a med school admissions committee, but among people i know who went to med school it's *very* common to fill prerequisites as a non-matriculating student.

Comment: As an ex-premed, I can attest to this. That being said, I believe most chemistry classes require lab time, so I don't believe taking them online is an option if you were considering that.